# Why was an edit which improves an imprecise point of the original answer rejected?

Tags: discussion, editing

https://ell.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/122559

Two reviewers rejected it with the following reason:

> This edit deviates from the original intent of the post. Even edits that must make drastic changes should strive to preserve the goals of the post's owner.

The original post addresses the question by explaining how programming works on this condition. The original illustration of code is incorrect, and would arise misunderstanding to those who have no computer science background, therefore I made this edit. This is not a 'deviation from the original intent of the post', but a fix.

Comment: This site is about English, not code. The illustration does not need to compile to make the point; it’s pseudocode.

Comment: @ColleenV 'The illustration does not need to compile to make the point; it’s pseudocode.': There is a misunderstding. I have not mentioned about compiling, what I meant is that, the code in the original post is misleading: it is incorrect. It is impossible to spelling out numeric characters in the manner that OP illustrates, that is, handling every numbers 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, ... one by one, since that this is an infinite list. I don't understand why such a fix should be rejected.

Comment: @ColleenV I understand that it is pseudocode, and I have studied carefully OP's pseudocode style so that my edit is consistent. The problem is that, the pseudocode is incorrect and misleading.

Comment: Readers who visit here are not expected to be able to read code to understand an answer about English usage. The illustration is what the author intended, if it is misleading, a comment explaining that is the appropriate way to give constructive criticism about the illustration.

Comment: @ColleenV Thank you, I finally make it out. I think this is another consequence of my unconsciousness of [the guidance](https://ell.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/edit). Will you turn your comment into an answer so that I can accept it?

Answer (score 1):

As [ColleenV](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/users/9161/colleenv) pointed out, [the guidance](https://ell.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/edit) mentioned that an edit is usually done `without changing' the meaning of the original post. Your edit changes the meaning of the OP, and thus considered inappropriate.